# Using value from another table in insert

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I have really annoying problem. I have this query that I am sending from c# project. Problem is that I cannot succeed to use value from another table into my insert. Here is my sample of code:

```
INSERT Izdavanje (registracioniBrojKorisnika, imeKorisnika, identifikacioniBrojKnjige, vremeidatumIzdavanja) 
  VALUES (@rbKorisnika, 
         (SELECT imeKorisnika 
            FROM Korisnici 
           WHERE registracioniBrojKorisnika=@rbKorisnika),
          @idKnjige, 
         GetDate());
```

Comment: `INSERT INTO t (c1, c2, ...) SELECT... ` Where you can select columns and literals etc (i.e. expressions.)

Comment: @jarlh But I wanna pull just 1 or 2 values from another table, not all of them.

Comment: One or two columns, or one or two rows?

Comment: @jarlh I wanna do insert with 2 values that are from c# (I can do that without problem, of course) and 2 column values from row that have specific ID.

Comment: Put those values in the SELECT, i.e. `SELECT @rbKorisnika, imeKorisnika, @idKnjige...`

Comment: Okay. So I have 2 tables, A and B. I want to make query for table A that is gonna put 2 column values from table B from row with specific ID into my query for table A. Example:
INSERT tableA (value1, value2, value3)
VALUES (value2 (selected from column "name" from row with specific id from tableB), same for value3)
P.S. I suck at formatting comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just drop the VALUES clause:

```
INSERT INTO Izdavanje (registracioniBrojKorisnika, imeKorisnika, identifikacioniBrojKnjige, vremeidatumIzdavanja) 
  SELECT @rbKorisnika, imeKorisnika, @idKnjige, GetDate()
  FROM Korisnici 
  WHERE registracioniBrojKorisnika=@rbKorisnika
```

Comment: Thanks! It's working! You cannot believe how much trouble I had with this piece of code! My brain sometimes suck so badly. Gracias!

Comment: Sorry, one more question. What is correct syntax if I wanna pull 2 values, not 1?

Comment: Just add the appropriate column name in the list.

Answer (score 0):

May be, following query works perfectly for your issue. Just place proper datatype for @imeKorisnika variable.

```
DECLARE @imeKorisnika VARCHAR(50)
SELECT @imeKorisnika = imeKorisnika  FROM Korisnici  WHERE registracioniBrojKorisnika=@rbKorisnika

INSERT INTO Izdavanje (registracioniBrojKorisnika, imeKorisnika, identifikacioniBrojKnjige, vremeidatumIzdavanja) 
SELECT @rbKorisnika, @imeKorisnika, @idKnjige, GetDate()
```

Comment: I actually had that idea and I tried that but I couldn't make it work, I probably messed up something in my attempt! Thanks! :)